# calculate distance & time between two locations in android map V2

Tags: android, android-maps-v2

I'm doing an android application which i need to find Distance & travel time between two locations by giving two lat/lang points in android mapV2.

I'm using the example as http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/driving-distance-and-travel-time-duration-between-two-locations-in-google-map-android-api-v2/.

But this example takes the tapping  positions as source & destination positions.But i need to give lat/lang values & need to calculate that distance & time values for that two positions.How could i do that?Thanks.

Comment: Instead of tapping you need to pass your FirstPoint and SecondPoint. that's it.

Comment: 4 edittext fields, why ask this question ?

Comment: M D. Thanks for your reply.How could i pass lat/lang values instead of LatLng points on that example?Code is much appreciated.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will both places by parsing  this google map api:
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng="+ lat + "," + lon + &sensor=true"

then pass the addresses for get distance between two points.

then For Distance You should try this one,In my case it worked perfect:

```
 JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
                String finalpickmefrom_encoded;
                try {
                    finalpickmefrom_encoded = URLEncoder.encode(finalpickmefrom,"UTF-8");
                    String finaldropmeat_encoded = URLEncoder.encode(finaldropmeat,"UTF-8");
                    addressURLLL = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin="+finalpickmefrom_encoded+"&destination="+finaldropmeat_encoded+"&sensor=false";

                    Log.e("Address","URL"+addressURLLL);
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                 JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(addressURLLL);
                JSONArray addressComp = json.getJSONArray(TAG_SHOW);

                for(int i =0;i<addressComp.length();i++)
                {
                    JSONObject cc = addressComp.getJSONObject(i);

                    JSONArray legss = cc.getJSONArray("legs");

                    for (int j = 0; j < legss.length(); j++) {

                        JSONObject c = legss.getJSONObject(j);
                        JSONObject long_name = c.getJSONObject("distance");
                        String withoutaddvia = long_name.getString("text");
                        String [] strwithout = withoutaddvia.split("\\s+");

                        finalDistanceWithoutAddVia = strwithout[0];
                        String str2 = strwithout[1];

                        String valuess = long_name.getString("value");


                    Log.e("PostalCode","1>>"+long_name);
                    Log.e("PostalCode","2>>"+finalDistanceWithoutAddVia);
                   Log.e("PostalCode","3>>"+valuess);
            }

                }
```

Here "finalDistanceWithoutAddVia" will be the distance.